# tikz: inner separator only in one dimension/border

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a way to increase the separator for a tikz object only for one border.

applying just a small 'inner sep' value and/or/no 'inner ysep' the title object blends into the text
[image: no inner ysep]

if I increase the 'inner ysep' it looks better but is symmetric for the nothern and southern border
[image: inner ysep increased]

Actually, I would like to control just the nothern border separator.
Maybe somebody has an idea for me?

Cheers and thanks,
  Thomas

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{headerbox} = [ultra thick,draw=green,rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{headerstyle} = [fill=yellow,rounded corners=5pt]
  \node[headerbox] (abstract1) {
    \begin{minipage}[H]{0.98\textwidth}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
  };
  \node[headerstyle] at (abstract1.north){\LARGE Abstract};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a rule at the begininning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{headerbox/.style = {ultra thick,draw=green,rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=10pt,
                            text width=0.98\textwidth,align=justify},
        headerstyle/.style = {fill=yellow,rounded corners=5pt}
   }
\large
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[headerbox] (abstract1) {
      \rule{0pt}{3ex}\lipsum[2]
  };
  \node[headerstyle] at (abstract1.north){\LARGE Abstract};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=white,boxsep=10pt,top=20pt,boxrule=1.5pt,colframe=green,
   title=Abstract,fontupper=\large,fonttitle=\LARGE,coltitle=black,arc=15pt,
    attach boxed title to top center=
     {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
      boxed title style={colback=yellow,colframe=yellow}]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is better done with `tcolorbox` and/or `mdframed`. I will add an example shortly.

Comment: thanks, that one works! 
I did not thought about such an approach ;)

Comment: @Thomas Do you want a `tcolorbox` solution?

Comment: uh, I am currently heavily relying on TikZ. At the moment I will stick to TikZ. But thanks for the offer!

Comment: @Thomas Anyway I have added an example. :-)